# Is an XA transaction really atomic?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel, xa, fuseesb

It seems that I'm not completely understand how an XA transaction works. I thought that it is atomic: I thought that when I commit a transaction, then new messages and new data will be available in the same time.

This misunderstanding led me to the following issue:
new rows are inserted to DB and a message is sent to a queue in a transactional route. In another route the message is received. Then this route tries to perform some manipulations with the rows that were inserted in the previous route. But it doesn't see them!

The second route is configured so it rolls back a message to the queue when an exception is happened. And I see that after a second run the route sees the rows!

As a conclusion I would ask the next questions:

1. Is an XA transaction really atomic?
2. If no, how can I configure commit order for my transactional resources?

**Additional note:** the issue is found in Fuse ESB/ServiceMix 4.4.1

---

**2 Jake:**
My camel context configuration looks like following:

```
<osgi:reference id="osgiPlatformTransactionManager" interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager"/>
<osgi:reference id="osgiJtaTransactionManager" interface="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>

<osgi:reference id="myDataSource"
       interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
       filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/postgresXADB)"/>

 <bean id="PROPAGATION_MANDATORY" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiPlatformTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_MANDATORY"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiPlatformTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="jmstx" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent"> 
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsTxConfig" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="jmsTxConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration"> 
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory"/> 
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiPlatformTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms.concurrentConsumers}" />
</bean> 

<bean id="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.XaPooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="${jms.maxConnections}" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiJtaTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsXaConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.broker.url}"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="-1"/>
            <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="2000" />
            <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="5000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

DB data source is configured as following:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource">
    <property name="serverName" value="${db.host}"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="${db.name}"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="${db.port}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>

<service ref="myDataSource" interface="javax.sql.XADataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/postgresXADB"/>
            <entry key="datasource" value="postgresXADB"/>
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

Comment: From what you have described here, it is not apparent if you have actually configured an XA transaction manager, or even two separate transactions, correctly. Can you please paste up your code?

Comment: 2 Jake: I've added more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this stuff, but my view would be that the atomicity that XA provides guaruntees only that:

- Either the entire commit occurs or the entire commit rolls back.
- That the whole commit/rollback completes before the commit request returns to whoever called it.

I don't think any guaruntee is made regarding the individual participants completing at the same instant, nor is there any kind of 'commit dependency tree' maintained guaranteeing that the subsequent processing only happens on participants who have committed.

I think to achieve what you want, you might need to put the message queue outside the main transaction... Which destroys the whole point of the transaction in the first place :(

I think you might just have to put a retry/timeout loop in your downstream processing. The alternative might be to explore the concurrency options to see if you an allow that downstream transaction to 'see' the upstream.

Hopefully this answer will prompt someone with more knowladge of this stuff to chip in!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I use AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY header as a workaround currently. But I hope that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

For XA transactions, when you commit, then camel will run `xa commit` for each DB, ensuring that all XA transaction will be committed eventually, not simultaneously. Since the data in each DB is committed separately, it is not atomic, and it is impossible to make data modification across database atomic.

For your application, there may be two choice to avoid the problem.

1. Don't use XA transactions, instead use OutBox pattern. You can update part of the data, send message to queue, and then return. Any order dependent operation is put into queue, where you can easily custom the order.
2. Base on your XA solution, when you want to read the newest data, you call `select for update`, which will wait for the row lock holding by unfinished XA transaction. When XA transactions returned, `select for update` will return the newest data.

Your `AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` header is a workaround, but not working when exceptions happen.